# Use Dependencies Within JAR File

Tags: java, jar

I am including a jar file that contains other jar dependencies within a project. When I attempt to use one of those dependencies in the new project it shows class not found errors. I can resolve these by duplicating the required jars in the new project's lib folder, but how can I use the existing dependencies located in the already included jar?

I've played around with exporting the jar as executable, but that hasn't resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Search for "fat jar". Maybe this helps you: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/packing-your-java-application-as-one-or-fat-jar.html

Comment: if it is an already included jar, classes will be already available on your classpath

Comment: Are you using a build tool such as gradle or maven? Sounds like you need to enable transitive dependencies.

Comment: I am not using maven...should I? The one-jar thing seems like the right path except I am not trying to create a single executable jar. The project is a WAR file that uses a couple of the third party dependencies already included in a jar that I control that is included in the project. I just didn't want to have to duplicate the third parties in the new project as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maven will resolve this issue automatically.
2. For Maven jars conflicts use exclusion this link may help https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html
3. Please review lib folder in WAR to make sure that there are no many versions of the same jar.